# I am stucked with this code of accessing values in 2D array using pointers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
    int a[4][2] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf("%d\n",*(a[2]+1));
    printf("%d\n", *(*(a + 2)+1));
    getch();
}
```

Two-dimensional array can be thought of as one-dimensional array.
    
output of this program is 6 in both printf. My question is how `printf("%d\n", *(*(a + 2)+1));` is executing and how precedence of asterik * and + evaluating.

Comment: I believe there is enough parenthesis, so you should not be confused about precedence, at all.

Comment: that results in `a[2][1]`.

Comment: if you are stuck with pointer arithmetics, just do not use it but use simple `a[2][1]` instead

Comment: How are you stuck exactly? Just look up the precedence order of operators.

Comment: What in the world about this question led to all the down votes?  Crimeny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider both your printf calls.

`a[2]` in cell is `int[2] = {5,6}`

`a[2] + 1` is a pointer which holds an address of number 6 (a[2] is implicitly converted to a pointer), so after the dereference it is 6.

`a` is and `int[4][2]` array, which is converted to a pointer (after conversion it holds the pointer to the first element)

`a + 2` is a pointer which holds an address of pointer to number 5

`*(a + 2)` is a pointer which holds address of number 5

`*(a + 2) + 1` is a pointer which holds address of number 6

`*(*(a + 2) + 1)` is number 6

EDIT:

Sorry, for some wrong statements. I take into account comments and I need to add that in above example lvalue expression of array type is implicitly converted to the pointer to its first element.

Comment: Actually `a[2]` and `*(a + 2)` are both a pointer which holds an address of the array of type `int[2]` which contains the numbers 5 and 6. Sure, the address of the array is the same as the address of the first number, but the type is different. Also, `a` as such is not a pointer. It is an array. However, when you pass `a` to the `+`-operator, the operand does *decay* to a pointer to the first element (which is the array {1,2}, not a number).

Comment: @user2079303 a[2] and *(a + 2) are not pointers. They are arrays. But used in expressions an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to tts first element.

Comment: `a[2]` is an array which decays into a pointer. `a[2] + 1` is indeed a pointer because `a[2]` has decayed. `a` is a 2D array which decays into a pointer to the first element (an array of two integers). `a + 2` performs pointer arithmetic on array basis: take `a`, it decays to a pointer to an array of 2 int, therefore increase the address with 2*2*sizeof(int) = 16. This part of your answer is incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow aww, my bad, I made the same mistake as kosmo16 that I corrected on in the next part of my comment :D how silly of me.

Comment: Several of your statements are not correct (see comments from Vlad and Lundin), and are unfortunately misleading OP to  learn (and accept) wrong concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a one dimensional array as for example

```
int a[] = { 5, 6 };
```

then expression `a[1]` is equivalent to expression `*( a + 1 )` and yields the second element of the array that is equal to `6`.

Array `a` from your example

```
int a[4][2] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

can be rewritten the following way for the clarity

```
int a[4][2] = { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 5,6 }, { 7,8 } };
```

You also can introduce a typedef name for the array

```
typedef int T[2];
```

where name `T` denotes type `int[2]`.

Using this typedef you can rewrite the declaration (the initialization may be omitted) of the original array the following way

```
T a[4];
```

Now let's consider expression `*(*(a + 2)+1)`. Subexpression `*(a + 2)` is equivalent to `a[2]` and as explained above will give the third element of the array of type `T` where T has type `int[2]`. So the object of this subexpression will be in turn one dimensioanl array of type `T` and correspond to the third element of array `a`. We can imagine it like

```
T tmp = { 5,6 };
```

or

```
int tmp[2] = { 5,6 };
```

Thus expression `*(*(a + 2)+1)` is equivalent to expression `*( tmp + 1 )` that equivalent to `tmp[1]` and will yield the second element of this imaginable array tmp. That is you will get `6`.

Comment: If asked what time it was, I suspect you would go into the properties of crystals, springs, quartz, etc, and finish by telling me what time it is.

Comment: @ryyker  I am sorry I have not understood your comment. Did you down-vote the answer? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @ryyker C is C. You must actually understand all the dirty details to use it safely. It is not a high level language where you can just call `for(me) { Write.Program(With2dArrays); } `.

Comment: @Lundin -  Regarding: _You must actually understand_ ***all*** _the dirty details to use it safely_.  Well, eventually, but _not at first_.     C, like other languages, is best learned in phases.  Fundamentals have to be solidly understood before abstract concepts can be digested by a student.  Based on the nature of this question, it appears OP is still a student, at least with respect to fundamentals of pointers and arrays.  BTW, I did not down vote Vlad's answer.  Ironically though I am perplexed why a question resulting in two good answers was down voted 4 times.  Seems a good question.

Comment: No, I did not down vote. However my comment was intended to convey my feeling that in answering, you traveled from Paris to Seville via the polar route. The first 8 lines, and the last two were sufficient to answer OP. Introducing the typedef concept, although not incorrect, was a distraction from the main question. (IMO).  My observations notwithstanding, +1.  This _is_ a useful answer.